# close dropdown menu with js on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

i had asked a question on closing dropdown with pure css [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885755/close-dropdown-menu-on-click-pure-css/24886804#24886804) and some said it is not possible to i had to find other way i read on js and im currently doing the coding with js now but i had one problem with the code it is not behaving properly it show all the dropdown and destroyed the submenu as well..any tutorial on this is appreciated or any suggestion here is the fiddle i made for this problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/gvmRX/18/)

this is the js

```
$(function () {
      $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
      $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
      $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
        $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
        $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      $(document).click(function() {
        if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
          $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
          $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvmRX/23/)

You have to add some function like following:

```
    $(function () {
  $('.click-nav .no-js .have-second-level-menu').click(function(e) {
     $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.have-third-level-menu').click(function(e) {
      $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

And Html will be like following:

```
<div id="headermenu" class="click-nav">
<ul class="no-js">
    <li id=""><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
    <li id=""><a class="have-second-level-menu" href="#">menu2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li ><a class="have-third-level-menu" href="#">submenu1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>           
</ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: your fiddle doesnt close the dropdown what i want is when i click on the dropdown it will close the dropdown